# Resize Images with .htaccess for website in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am following this tutorial [here](http://sneak.co.nz/projects/img-resizing/)
and unconventionally for me, my situation is for a website that is NOT pointed to the root directory, but rather a subfolder.

*mydomain.com* is pointed to a path that looks like

```
/webroot/sites/sitename
```

the images are stored as

```
subdomain.mydomain.com/img/uploads/filename.jpg
```

I am editing the .htaccess file located in */webroot/sites/sitename* and NOT the webroot.

Here is the content of my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN ImageResizing
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# scaling small, medium, large
RewriteRule ^img/small/subdomainfolder/img/uploads/([A-Za-z0-9/_-]+).(jpg|gif|png)$ images.php?max_width=100&imgfile=$1.$2
</ifmodule>
# END ImageResizing
```

As you can imagine, this does not work. Any help?

note: I have placed the *cache* folder and *image.php* file within */webroot/sites/sitename*

Comment: What is full filesystem path of `filename.jpg` what is your DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: it will look something like this @anubhava http://learn.edupal.io/img/uploads/MountOlympos.jpg-Back-29-12-39-48-317-1440866389.png
I want to be able to load it as 
http://learn.edupal.io/small/img/uploads/MountOlympos.jpg-Back-29-12-39-48-317-1440866389.png

Comment: Both URLs have just a difference of `/small/` in front? Is that correct?

Comment: @anubhava correct. per the tutorial, the /small/ should allow me to change any image loaded with the directory in the URL path

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^small/(img/.+?\.(?:jpg|gif|png))$ $1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: tried and no dice. Just a 404 error http://learn.edupal.io/small/img/uploads/MountOlympos.jpg-Back-29-12-39-48-317-1440866389.png
we also need to pass this in there somehow $ images.php?max_width=100&imgfile=$1.$2

Comment: Make sure this is first rule and you test with `R` flag as in: `RewriteRule ^small/(img/.+?\.(?:jpg|gif|png))$ $1 [L,NC,R]`

Comment: The only thing inside the .htaccess file is the code from my question's details with the edits of your answer. 404 error persists

Comment: What is full path of your DocumentRoot? This htaccess should be right under DocumentRoot